# Bitmap in ImageView with rounded corners

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, rounded-corners

I have an ImageView and I want to make it with `rounded corners`.

I use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid  android:color="@null"/>    

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>


    <corners android:radius="62px"/> 
</shape>
```

And set this code as background of my imageview.
It works, but the src image that I put on the `ImageView` is going out of the borders and doesn't adapt itself into the new shape.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695023/how-to-create-a-background-with-image-rounded-corners-without-borders/16695407#16695407. check this might help

Comment: Setting `padding` for you `ImageView` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

try this one :

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    public static float radius = 18.0f;  

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //float radius = 36.0f;  
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and

```
<your.pack.name.CustomImageView
                android:id="@+id/selectIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

CustomImageView  iconImage = (CustomImageView )findViewById(R.id.selectIcon);
iconImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

or,

```
ImageView iv= new CustomImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
```

Comment: Thank you @Anand for sharing this, but I am not getting sharp edges for circle, would please!! guide me what would be radius for Image size is 40X40 dp.

Comment: Note that in general you shouldn't make object allocations during draw or layout methods.  It's fairly straightforward to move these allocations into other parts of the view object.

Comment: @Salim, so is there any way to have only top left corner?

Comment: The best solution for me. Simple and clever.

Comment: hi it only works for me if i add myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null). Any reason why it doesn't work otherwise?

Comment: Hmm.. But you should know that path clipping doesn't support anti-aliasing. See Romain Guy's comments on his post. "path clipping does not support antialiasing and you get jagged edges." http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Comment: For me it works nicely with android version 5.0.1 but it doesn't work with 4.0.4. I figured already out that 4.0.4 doesn't support the canvas.clipPath function. Therefore I tried already [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895677/work-around-canvas-clippath-that-is-not-supported-in-android-any-more) but it doesn't work for me... does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: I used this class but corners are not smooth. Can you suggest what should I do to smooth the corners?

Answer (score 39):

It's strange that nobody here has mentioned [RoundedBitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html%20RoundedBitmapDrawable) from Android Support Library v4. For me it is the simplest way to get rounded corners without borders. Here is example of usage:

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
final float roundPx = (float) bitmap.getWidth() * 0.06f;
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(roundPx);
```

Comment: I have an issue... setting corner radius causes to change position of image! Try yourself: Set bound of `RoundedBitmapDrawable` > see result without setting corner radius. Now set corner radius and see result again!

Comment: so easy and complete

Comment: It's worth noting that you can't use the bitmap of this drawable for further processing as it's not rounded.

Comment: Finally! All the other solutions would not allow me to have a rounded button that ALSO had a rounded background.

Answer (score 24):

Make one function which make rounded to your bitmap using canvas.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

for more info:> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473113/bitmap-image-with-rounded-corners-with-stroke)

Comment: This is neat!
(Be sure to increase the pixel count considerably if it seems to not be working for you)

Comment: I'm drawing bitmap on canvas along with shadow, for making shadow rounded this is my steps, `mPaint.setShadowLayer(radius, dX, dY, shadowColor);canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, mPaint);` and making bitmap corner rounded using your code but `shadow` and `bitmap` corners are differs from one-another, what should i do?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer uses path clipping, but it doesn't support anti-aliasing. See Romain Guy's comments on his post. "path clipping does not support antialiasing and you get jagged edges."

http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

There is one good library(vinc3m1’s RoundedImageView) that supoorts rounded corners on ImageView, but it only supports the same radiuses on every corners. So I made one that you can set different radiuses on each corners.

It doesn't rely on path clipping, nor redrawing. It only draws one time with `canvas.drawPath()` method. So I finally got result that I wanted like below.

[image]

See : https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

Answer (score 7):

For me, the below method does the magic. :)
This method accepts a bitmap object and returns it back with rounded corners. `roundPx` is the number of rounded pixels you want:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 12;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

...or you could use [this](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library instead of **ImageView** without any further coding.

Comment: Plagiarism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/4788546.

Comment: @CristiFati I never said I invented the method. I said it worked for me at the time. When answering the question, I didn't notice this method in the link you shared.

Answer (score 6):

If you need make Bitmap with different corner radii and I recommend follow code:

```
private static Bitmap createRoundedRectBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap,
                                float topLeftCorner, float topRightCorner,
                                float bottomRightCorner, float bottomLeftCorner) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 
                                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = Color.WHITE;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    Path path = new Path();
    float[] radii = new float[]{
            topLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner,
            topRightCorner, topRightCorner,
            bottomRightCorner, bottomRightCorner,
            bottomLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner
    };

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    path.addRoundRect(rectF, radii, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: The second element should be topLeftCorner rather than bottomLeftCorner, then it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you need border also then:
1. You can use a rounded box image with a transparent body and white from outside. For Example:

[image: Rounded box]

and use this with target image like below:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="100px"
android:layout_height="100px" >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/targetImage"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/boxImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />
```

2. Adding [CardView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview) as parent layout of `ImageView` also be a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with background drawable, like explain in many posts including this one, but it also needs to set clipping.
Here a full example:

The code:

```
AppCompatImageView iconView = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
iconView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

The layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="@drawable/round_view" <!--here set the drawable as background -->
    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_user" />
```

The drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Creates new circular bitmap based on original one.
 * @param newCornerRadius is optional
 */
fun Bitmap.toCircular(context: Context, newCornerRadius: Float? = null): RoundedBitmapDrawable {
    return RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.resources, this).apply {
        isCircular = true
        newCornerRadius?.let {
            cornerRadius = it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Bitmap rounder = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvasRound = new Canvas(rounder);    

        Paint xferPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        xferPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        final int rx = this.getWidth(); //our x radius
        final int ry = this.getHeight(); //our y radius

        canvasRound.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,rx,ry), rx, ry, xferPaint);     

        xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        canvas.drawBitmap(rounder, 0, 0, xferPaint);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin version**

```
fun Bitmap.roundCorner(pixels: Int): Bitmap {
        val output: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(output)
        val color = -0xbdbdbe
        val paint = Paint()
        val rect = Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        val rectF = RectF(rect)
        val roundPx = pixels.toFloat()
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
        paint.color = color
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint)
        paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        canvas.drawBitmap(this, rect, rect, paint)
        return output
}
```

call by:
`sourceBitmap.roundCorner(60)`

Answer (score -4):

The method to make rounded corners for imageview in android is not rocket science guys! just use a png with required curves with the same color as your background and set the overlay to FITXY.!

Comment: What if the image comes from a server.

Answer (score -4):

```
public void drawRoundImage(boolean isEditPicEnable){
   if(originalImageBitmap != null){
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_account_user_outer_circle_blue);

        if (isEditPicEnable) {
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_account_user_outer_circle_white);
            Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_account_white_mask);
            Bitmap mask1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_account_pencil_bg);
            originalImageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalImageBitmap, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), true);
            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(originalImageBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask1, 0, 0, null);
            Bitmap mask2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_account_pencil);
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask2, 0, 0, null);
            setImageBitmap(result);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        } else {
            Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_account_white_mask);
            originalImageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalImageBitmap, mask.getWidth(),mask.getHeight(), true);
            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(originalImageBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(null);
            setImageBitmap(result);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }

    }else{
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_account_user_outer_circle_blue);
        setImageResource(R.drawable.my_ac_default_profile_pic);
    }

}
```

Comment: While this answer *may* solve the question that was posted, it is recommended that you add some human-readable text too that explains what the code does or where it is different from the OP's code. As it is now, it's just a code-dump that doesn't even explain why this is any good.