# How can I set a background image with rounded corners

Tags: android

I want to create a background that is an image and also give it rounded corners. I have the following code. the background image shows but there is no rounded corners.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/tabs_pattern_diagonal"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I have tried changing the order of the times but it made no difference

**edit**

I dont have an imageview. this layerlist is being applied as a background to a linearlayout

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitmap in ImageView with rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229358/bitmap-in-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: here is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) if you don't want to implement rounded corners yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 12;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
  }
```

[Source](http://ruibm.com/?p=184)

You can also refer to [article by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp" >
        <corners
         android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
      android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/tabs_pattern_diagonal"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```