# Make ImageView with Round Corner Using picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I know there are lots of link available to make `ImageView` Round Corner.
But I'm Using `Picasso` Library for Image Loading..
I refer the [link](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) to get result.
But the Problem is that I'm Using it in **`ListView`** and for the `LIstView's` first item `ImageView` its working perfectly fine but for the remaining once transformation is not working.

Comment: Have you tried this transformation?
https://gist.github.com/aprock/6213395

Usage: Picasso.with(context).load(url).transform(new RoundedTransformation()).into(imageView)

Comment: @RoiDivon I just used link you provided, But it also giving the the same effect..

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I am using this transformation:
https://gist.github.com/julianshen/5829333

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Superb!!! Thanks a lot...I just replace `canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);` with `canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()), r, r, paint);` to get round corner rect

Comment: You forgot to say that the r needs to be changed for this to work, otherwise it makes the circle from RoundRect because the radius is too big.

Comment: And both forgot to say that you need to change r for 0 and size.getHeight() for it to work (in my case). This is the final code: `canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()), 0, source.getHeight(), paint);`

Answer (score 40):

You can use [RoundedCornersTransformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/picasso/transformations/RoundedCornersTransformation.java) class of [picasso-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) library.

Example :

```
final int radius = 5;
final int margin = 5;
final Transformation transformation = new RoundedCornersTransformation(radius, margin);
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).transform(transformation).into(imageView);
```

Comment: if we set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to the `ImageView` and image is zoomed to fill out the view, then your method doesn't take any effect because rounded corners are out of view

Comment: @Choletski use also CropTransformation(int width, int height) before RoundedCornersTransformation

Comment: @Choletski, probably `centerCrop()` may help: `Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri).centerCrop().resize(width, height).transform(transformation).into(imageView);`.

Answer (score 31):

You can use this class to make rounded corners rectangle image view with Picasso, use it like this

```
 Picasso.with(activity).load(url).transform(new RoundedCornersTransform(this)).into(imageView);
```

Here is the class RoundedCornersTransform.

```
package com.demo.picasso;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;


public class RoundedCornersTransform implements Transformation {
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    float r = size / 8f;
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()), r, r, paint);
    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
public String key() {
    return "rounded_corners";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is short n perfect solution in all posts about rounded corner transform on SO. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How do I use this @stevyhacker to make only the top two corners rounded... I cannot understand what part I am suppose to change?

Comment: @Lion789:
In the [picasso-transformations library](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/picasso/transformations/RoundedCornersTransformation.java) mentionded below, it is possible to exactly set the corners that you want rounded, e.g:

Picasso
.with(mContext)
.load(mUrl)
.resize(200, 200)
.centerCrop()
.transform( new RoundedCornersTransformation(2, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.LEFT) )
.into(mImageView);

Comment: @Lion789 I got all the rounded corners with the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42380519/2819864).

Answer (score 12):

i used `RoundedCornersTransformation`class of `picasso-transformations`library.  I had custom adapter with view holder pattern in my listview. I added below dependency in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
}
```

And in my `customArrayAdapter.java`,i added:

`Picasso.with(getContext()).load(path).transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(10,10)).resize(175,300).into(viewHolder.ivImage);`
This would both resize and give rounded corners to you images.

Answer (score 8):

Like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33911497/2425851). You can use `MaskTransformation`class of [picasso-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) library.

Example :

```
final Transformation transformation = new MaskTransformation(getContext(), R.drawable.rounded_convers_transformation);
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).transform(transformation).into(imageView);
```

**res/drawable/rounded_convers_transformation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

UPDATE: But notice that you should also `.resize(w,h)` the image, because if image will be large the round will not be determinatable

Comment: Nice solution. Also note that before you apply this transformation `ImageView` must be visible (in other case no transformation will be applied). And yes, you can write `Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri).centerCrop().resize(width, height).transform(transformation).into(imageView);` for cropped images.

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin version of RoundCornerTransform based on @stevyhacker 's answer.

- Support rectangle instead of square image.
- No extra 3rd party library needed.

=============================================

```
import android.graphics.*
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation

class RoundCornersTransform(private val radiusInPx: Float) : Transformation {

    override fun transform(source: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.width, source.height, source.config)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        val shader = BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
        paint.shader = shader
        val rect = RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, source.width.toFloat(), source.height.toFloat())
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radiusInPx, radiusInPx, paint)
        source.recycle()

        return bitmap
    }

    override fun key(): String {
        return "round_corners"
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
    Picasso.get()
        .load(imageUrl)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
        .transform(RoundCornersTransform(32.0f))
        .into(imageView, callback)
```

Answer (score 3):

Following [@stevyhacker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241525/2819864) and [this related one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132723/2819864), I came up with this:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;


public class RoundedCornersTransform implements Transformation {
    private static Bitmap createRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,
                                                  float topLeftCorner, float topRightCorner,
                                                  float bottomRightCorner, float bottomLeftCorner) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = Color.WHITE;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        Path path = new Path();
        float[] radii = new float[]{
                topLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner,
                topRightCorner, topRightCorner,
                bottomRightCorner, bottomRightCorner,
                bottomLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner
        };

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        path.addRoundRect(rectF, radii, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        float r = size / 4f;

        Bitmap roundedBitmap = createRoundedRectBitmap(squaredBitmap, r, r, r, r);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();

        return roundedBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "rounded_corners";
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).transform(new RoundedCornersTransform()).into(imageView);
```

Probably needs some enhancements though, so watch out!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this source code

https://github.com/sminrana/picasso-android

## Picasso Rounded and Circle Transformation in Android

Add Picasso in your project

```bash
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
```

Get the source code of PicassoCircleTransformation and PicassoRoundedCornerTransformation

```java
final Transformation circleTransformation = new PicassoCircleTransformation();
Picasso.get()  
        .load(URL)  
        .transform(circleTransformation)  
        .into(ImageView);


final Transformation roundedTransformation = new PicassoRoundedCornerTransformation(32.0f);
Picasso.get().load(URL)  
        .transform(roundedTransformation)   
        .into(ImageView);
```

```java
package YOUR_PACKAGE;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

public class PicassoCircleTransformation implements Transformation {

    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;
        float r = size / 2f;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        Paint paintBg = new Paint();
        paintBg.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(0xFF141c26);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paintBg);
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r - 2, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override public String key() { return String.valueOf(Math.random()); }
}
```

```java
package YOUR_PACKAGE;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;

public class PicassoRoundedCornerTransformation implements Transformation {

    private float mRadius;

    public PicassoRoundedCornerTransformation(float radius) {
        this.mRadius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        float mMargin = 0.0f;
        float right = width - mMargin;
        float bottom = height - mMargin;
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);

        source.recycle();

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override public String key() { return String.valueOf(Math.random()); }
}
```