# Picasso Library rounded corners for placeholder

Tags: android, listview, picasso

Using, 
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).transform(new CircleTransform(22,12)).into(imageView); we can have rounded corners for loading image.But there is no rounded corners for placeholder nor error image?

Link which I reffered [Make ImageView with Round Corner Using picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704581/make-imageview-with-round-corner-using-picasso)

Comment: use glide with that you may do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with Picasso. See the answers [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/337).

Answer (score 7):

```
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).placeholder(setCircularImage(R.drawable.profile_sample)).error(setCircularImage(R.drawable.profile_sample)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ivMenuProfile);
```

add setCircularImage method with place holder for make placehoder in to circle view

```
private RoundedBitmapDrawable setCircularImage(int id) {
        Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = 
        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, src);
        roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
        return roundedBitmapDrawable;
    }
```

add CircleTransform() with transform for change shape in to circle for load Url Image.

```
public class CircleTransform  implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size/2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```