# how to make image view with three corner and shadow

Tags: android, xml, imageview, material-components-android

[image]

How to make an image with only three corners like this 
I tried using frame layout the insert image view and make it's resource with original image
the add another image view with src of border that has 3 corner bu it doesn't work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use the **`MaterialShapeDrawable`**.

Just use something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/onlyonecorner"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxx"
      ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="onlyonecorner">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

The `ShapeableImageView` requires a minimum of version **`1.2.0-alpha03`**.

Comment: any suggestion about shadow

Comment: did you find any solutiona about shadow? @KarimAta

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a rounded bitmap with Glide or Picasso. In this case you can write transformation. See, for instance, [Make ImageView with Round Corner Using picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704581/make-imageview-with-round-corner-using-picasso).

Then you can create an image with a shadow. After that overlap one image over another.

Comment: i don't wanted to be circle i want it to have three corners

Comment: @KarimAta, Yes, I mean your own transformation with one corner (if it is possible). Or create a circle and overlay with 1/4 of the image in the top-right angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#587E9B">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**drawable/my_shape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="12dp" />
<solid android:color="#CF2525" />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="60dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="60dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```

---

Here is how it will look:

[image]

Now all you need to do is to change the `corners` inside `drawable/my_shape`

Comment: i want to have image with three corner not other view

Comment: Maybe you can use cardView like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479670)

Comment: Another good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57834981/8274756)