# Android ImageView nested in a CardView - doesn't show round corners

Tags: android, imageview, android-cardview, rounded-corners

I'm trying to show an image with a rounded view inside a cardview, and strangely I don't get the corners of the image rounded but flat. I'm compiling with API level 29.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/thumb"
                            android:layout_width="370dp"
                            android:layout_height="370dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                            app:cardElevation="0dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail" />
```

Worth noting I'm using Picasso to load the image. Any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

expected results:
[image: That's the expected result:]

actual result:
[image: That's the real output:]

Comment: when loading img with picasso, you can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30707381/11178991

Comment: @AyTee - I'd rather use the layout XML instead of coding this as in your attached link, just to keep consistency with other practices I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use above attribute in `ImageView`:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```