# Curved Bottom part of Bitmap image Android

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, bitmapimage, curve

Good day guys.I want to make the bottom part of my own image an curved line.Not to talk back and forth here is an image which i want to get into the application.
Important to notice that i have reached 10th result of the google and everything i came up was only some curved image not in my desired way,the whole image was curved and the lines of 4 parts were connected to single one.
So basically i want the image to be as rectangle as it comes from server and only curve the bottom part of a bitmap.Is that even possible?[image]

Noticae the bottom line is curved,that what i want to achieve,and rest parts are rectangle.Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK what i understood is you want to curved drawable which will suits to your design am i right?

Comment: hey, for bottom curved view, now you have to make an image with gray or white background. And apply this as a background to your bottom views parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the image itself, photoshop or any editing tool is the right way to do it. besides if  you are getting the image from a server somewhere then getting the image adjusted from the server, instead of modifying it on the client side(o your app) has lot of benefits. 
But, if want to change the look not the image itself, then that could be achieved by creating a custom image view like answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229358/bitmap-in-imageview-with-rounded-corners)
You can also use a card view hold your image view to achieve some curves, although i don't think that would be efficient or satisfactory for your case.

Comment: anyway the performance is not the right option on my side so i basically agree with you though

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, editing the image in Photoshop is the right way. This can save your android app CPU time.

Comment: your right but sometimes i guess you should read a little carefull to notice that i receive image from backend ,meaning i cant receive image from server,tell user to wait untill i manually edit in photoshop and put back into app -.- this is purely pointless answer

Comment: one solution you can do is override the onDraw of View, then manually create curved mask on top of the image.

Comment: ok i thought about that too,but how then i get the bitmap from canvas?

Comment: i think it is not possible to get the bitmap from the canvas. however, you said it is coming from the server. so you already have the reference to your bitmap before passing it to your canvas. keep the reference maybe?