# How to design drawable left icon as circular (added using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds) in Textview using java code (not xml)

Tags: java, android, textview, android-drawable

I have a text view with icon rendered in the TextView. It has an image. I have set on the left of the text. But I need to set the icon as a circular shape.

How can I design this in java?

[image]

My code which set on the left side.

```
textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    image, 0, 0, 0);
```

How can I design the circular image for the above textview drawableleft image.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:minHeight="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_d2"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_d2"
        android:tag="@string/tag_font_h_regular"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cachetbook"
        android:textColor="@color/white_new"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        tools:text="Universal Orlando Resort"/>
```

Comment: Can you add expected output Image with question ?

Comment: Updated my question with image. I need like the above left side image needs to be circular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Load your image

You need to load your image as a bitmap. If you are taking if from your drawable, you can see [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap).

#### Resize it

You can resize your bitmap to scale it to fit your textview as you wish. See [How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android).

#### Make the corner rounded

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698127/10160890) you can found the code to make corner rounded

#### Code example

```
// Load your drawable
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
// Convert it to a bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(drawableToBitmap((drawable)),50,50,false);
// Make the corner rounded
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
final float roundPx = (float) bitmap.getWidth() * 90f;
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(roundPx);
// Apply it to the TextView
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.test)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                roundedBitmapDrawable, null, null, null);
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Note

I do not know why you decided to choose to do it programmatically, but I would not recommand it, it is harder to control the view and how things are positionned.

Comment: drawableToBitmap((drawable)) is not resolved for me

Comment: Yes, the function is defined here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/10160890 as written is the answer.