# How to make the corner of an image inside ImageView round?

Tags: android

I am having this problem and I know it's common, the problem is that I have already applied the code to draw, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/1968739). Now, since my `ImageView` has set width and height which is `50dp`, the rounded corner is not achieved.

So I used the xml alternative, here it is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#999999" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
             android:top="2dp"
             android:right="2dp"
             android:bottom="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

I made this as background of the ImageView, the problem now is that the only affected of the round corner is the ImageView itself and not its content image. The image's normal (rectangle or sharp) edge still overlapped its container which is the ImageView. I also set this `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in my `ImageView`.

I am now confused, so setting the ImageView's width and height forfeits the effect of the rounded corner? What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695023/how-to-create-a-background-with-image-rounded-corners-without-borders/16695407#16695407. check this

Comment: use canvas to draw the shape

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen I have. I used code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/1968739).

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x not sure how you have used but it works for me the one in the link i posted

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example:
https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Check it out.

Comment: I am having trouble running the project `roundedimageview`, its project target is API level 8 and the class method `setBackground` occured an error so I changed it to API level 16. After running from Eclipse, it didn't display anything in the device. Did I miss anything?

Comment: There are 2 projects. The 1st is 'roundedimageview', after importing it, open Properties > Android > set 'Is Library' checked.
The 2nd is 'example', after importing it, open Properties > Android > under library section select 'Add' and choose the 'roundedimageview', and then click 'OK'.
Build the 1st project and then the 2nd. Now, run the 2nd and it should open.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
public static Bitmap getRoundCorneredBitmapFrom(Bitmap bitmap,int cornerRadius)  {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (cornerRadius < 0) {
            cornerRadius = 0;
        }
        // Create plain bitmap
        Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = getCanvas(canvasBitmap);

        Paint paint = getPaint();

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return canvasBitmap;
    }
  private static Canvas getCanvas(Bitmap bitmap) {
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
     canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
     return canvas;
  }
  private static Paint getPaint() {
     Paint paint = new Paint();
     paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     return paint;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it seems that the methods `getCanvas()` and `getPaint()` are undefined.

Comment: run above code from non UI thread as it takes some time to run